# Zf1/Zwig/Twig integration failed

Tags: zend-framework, twig

I've got a problem integrating Twig and Zend Framework 1, with the Zwig library alb/zwig,

Versions are

alb/zwig version 1.0.1
twig/twig 1.14.2
zf1 1.12.3

The result is:

- module controller action call is fine
- layout.twig is properly displayed (parent() works)
- index.twig specific block content is not displayed

Trials:
several downgrades, no step by step debug performed

application/configs/application.ini

```
    twig.templateDir = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/%module%/views/scripts/"
    ;twig.options.cache = APPLICATION_PATH "/../cache/twig"
    autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Twig_"
    autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Zwig_"
    autoloaderNamespaces[] = "ZFDebug_"
    resources.modules[] = ""
    
    resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/Layout/views/scripts/"
    resources.layout.layout = "layout"
```

**application/Bootstrap.php**

```
    public function _initLayout() {
        $layout = $this->getPluginResource("layout")->getLayout();
        $layout->setViewSuffix("twig");
    }
    
    protected function _initTwig() {
        Twig_Autoloader::register();
        $config = Zend_Registry::get('config');
        $templatePath = array();
    
        $view = new Zwig_View(array(
            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
            'helperPath' => array(
            ),
        ));
        $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem();
        $d = new DirectoryIterator($config->resources->frontController->moduleDirectory);
        foreach ($d as $fileInfo) {
            zif (!$fileInfo->isDot() && $fileInfo->isDir()) {
                $moduleName = $fileInfo->getFilename();
                $templatePath =
                    str_replace(
                        '%module%', $moduleName, $config->twig->templateDir
                    );
                $loader->addPath($templatePath, strtolower($moduleName));
            }
        }
        $zwig = new Zwig_Environment($view, $loader, array(
            'debug' => true,
            'cache' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/cache/twig/',
            //'auto_reload' => true,
        ));
        $view->setEngine($zwig);
        $view->doctype(Zend_View_Helper_Doctype::XHTML1_STRICT);
    
        $viewRenderer = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer($view, array(
            'viewSuffix' => 'twig',
        ));
    
        Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($viewRenderer);
        return $view;
    }
```

## application/modules/Login/controllers/IndexController.php

```
class Login_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        // action body
        $this->view->toto = "texte";
    }
}
```

## application/modules/Layout/views/scripts/layout.twig

```
    {# empty Twig template #}
    
    
        
        Titre de la page        
    
    
        {% block header %}
            
        {%endblock header %}
        
        {% block content %}
            
         eéâà
            
        {% endblock content %}
            
        {% block sidebar %}
            
        {% endblock sidebar %}
            
        ceci est un contenu de page
```

child template

```
    # cat application/modules/Login/views/scripts/index/index.twig 
    {% extends '@layout/layout.twig' %}
    
    {% block content %}
    {{ parent() }}
    
    {{ toto }}
    
    {% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the default view suffix?

```
$this->getHelper('viewRenderer')->setViewSuffix('twig');
```

This should also be settable from your config file.

Comment: It is in application/Bootstrap.php in _initTwig and _initLayout methods. I should have gotten a "File template not found", right ?

Comment: Yes, maybe you should have had gotten that error.
Sorry I don;t know what the issue might be then.
Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: It is not a matter of extension it is supplied two time in the source code. I investigated with xdebug, not found the problem nut extension is right, seems that the child tmeplate is not rendered in  a way I don't understand right now, digging into twig/zwig code ...

Comment: Does the web server user have permissions to read the template file?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, in application/Bootstrap.php _initLayout() function and application.ini related conf **must be removed**. This conflicts with twig inheritance.

application/Booststrap.php

```
    /*
    public function _initLayout() {
        $layout = $this->getPluginResource("layout")->getLayout();
        $layout->setViewSuffix("twig");
    }
    */
```

application.ini

```
    ;resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/Layout/views/scripts/"
    ;resources.layout.layout = "layout"
```